# VBS: Type conflict when using a variable with application.run

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I'd like to use a vbs-file as a bridge to get access from Java to a vba-macro which is inside an Excel file. Additionally, I need to transmit some variable parameters.

In  Java I call open the vbs-file like this (works fine):

```
         String strFileName = "mappe2.xlsm"; //located in the same directory
         String strMacroName = "showname";
         String strParameter = "Myname";

         String[] command = {"wscript.exe", f.getAbsolutePath(), strFileName, strMacroName, strParameter};
         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

In Excel I just try to call this simple sub:

```
Sub showname(strName As String)
     MsgBox ("The name is: " & strName) 
End Sub
```

And my (shortened) vbs-file looks like this:

```
Dim args, ExcelFileName, ExcelMacroName
Dim opt
Dim Command2
Set args = WScript.Arguments
ExcelFileName = args(0)
ExcelMacroName = args(1)
opt = Cstr(args(2))
Set objWbk = GetObject("E:\Mappe2.xlsm")

Command2 = ExcelFileName & "!" & "showname"

'objWbk.Application.Run Command2, "opt" 'This way it works!
objWbk.Application.Run Command2, opt 'Error: "Type conflict" occurs!

WScript.Quit
```

And here you can see that the call for the macro with a static "opt" works fine. But since I change it to a varible I get the error of type conflict and I don't know why. I need to have it variable.

Can you help me?

Comment: this is just a wild guess really but try to call `objWbk.Application.Run Command2, Eval(opt)`

Comment: Thanky you for this try! At least the macro gets started, but the parameter isn't transmitted correctly. So opt is empty and the Msgbox shows up like this: "The name is: "

Comment: Are you sure that args(2) is not null?

Comment: Sorry I see that you have found it is empty.  You need to debug and have a look at exactly what is in args

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's not empty. I checked it already with "WScript.Echo args(2)". The value "Myname" is transmitted correctly.

Comment: I can't answer my own question yet, so I need to use the comment-function.

So at least I found a workaround. I can only show how it works, not why. If someone can explain why please let me and the others know.

Here, opt gets the value of args(2):

    opt = args(2)

Next, both show the same value:

    wscript.echo "opt : " & opt 
    wscript.echo "args(2) : " & args(2)

I can't use opt as a variable to run my macro:

    objWbk.Application.Run Command2, opt

But it works if I use the arguments-collection directly:
    objWbk.Application.Run Command2, args(2)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to format this comment, but I can't! I hope you can still understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is beacuase your `sub showname(strName As String)` requires a **String** as Argument.
Even thoug your variable `opt` contains a String, it is of type `Variable`
To pass the variable, explicitely transform opt as a string `objWbk.Application.Run Command2, Cstr(opt)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I tried the first one but you can't declare a String this way in VBScript. 
But the second method works fine. It's interesting to notice that you need to make the transformation to a string when calling the macro with the run-method. It doesn't work when I try to make the transformation some lines earlier: `opt = CStr(args(2))`

Comment: Just one more question: When I check the type of `opt` via `wscript.echo Typename(opt)` it shows `String` and doesn't matter if I check before or after the run statement. How can a String in VBS be not a String in VBA?

Comment: @Eleandro, All variables in VBScript are of type _Variant_. You can read about them on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). Basically, Variant is a special type that can hold one of several different types. The TypeName function shows you the subtype (that is, the type of variable the Variant is holding).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to wait as a new user before I could answer my own question. I'd like to do it now because it's much better to read.

Well, it least I found a workaround. I can't explain why it doesn't work with the variable, but I'll show how my solution works. If someone can explain why please let me and the others know.

So lets do it step by step:

Here, opt gets the value of args(2):

```
opt = args(2)
```

Next, both show the same value (both display "Myname" as declared in my java method):

```
wscript.echo "opt : " & opt 
wscript.echo "args(2) : " & args(2)
```

I can't use opt as a variable to run my macro:

```
objWbk.Application.Run Command2, opt  'Error: Type conflict!
```

But it works if I use the arguments-collection directly:

```
objWbk.Application.Run Command2, args(2)
```

For me it's fine now because currently I don't need to change the received parameters; i can just simply forward them to the macro. But if someone needs to transmit any different values with a variable I'm afraid he can't do it this way. If someone knows a solution please let me know!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that changing the Excel method signature to:

```
Sub showname(strName As Variant)
```

allowed me to pass `opt` in my testing. I really don't have a good explanation about why that would work, though.

Comment: This will work because `opt` is dimentioned as a Variant.  Therefore the argument passed and the argument expected have the same type.